Electron speed in the classical atom
In the classical (Bohr) model of the atom, does an electron in an outer orbit travel at a greater or slower speed than an electron in an inner orbit?

The kinetic energy $$E_k = \langle \psi | {p^2 \over 2m} | \psi \rangle$$ is smaller for outer electrons than for inner electrons.

I would stress already in the title that the question has to do with Bohr's model.

Possibly related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/365493/174766

Can you explain what is preventing you from calculating it yourself?

If you know how to  calculate  the velocity in Bohrs model, the same calculation applies to the grater radius. So v gets smaller an you can calculate it.

For Bohr (outdated) atom model, equate centripetal force to the Coulomb electrostatic force which is the reason for electron centripetal acceleration :
$${\frac {m_{\mathrm {e} }v^{2}}{r}}={\frac {Zk_{\mathrm {e} }e^{2}}{r^{2}}} \tag 1$$
and express tangential speed $v(r)$ as a function of orbital radius $r$ to get an answer. It's a simple DIY thing.
